# Instagram update to 5.0. How can I set "InstagramCaption" programmatically with iPhone hooks

Tags: ios, instagram

As Instagram official document says

> To include a pre-filled caption with your photo, you can set the annotation property on the document interaction request to an NSDictionary containing an NSString under the key "InstagramCaption". Note: this feature will be available on Instagram 2.1 and later.

For Instagram 4.x or lower, it works well. But for Instagram 5.0, Instagram team added a new feature called "Direct". When users upload a photo, they have two options "Followers" or "DIRECT". I think this is the reason why "InstagramCaption" doesn't work. Is there a new way to add caption programmatically?

Thank you so much!

```
    self.dic.annotation = @{@"InstagramCaption" : captionString};
    self.dic.delegate = self;
    [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:shareButton.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

It doesn't work now.

Comment: Running into the same issue - our users that update instagram to 5.0 can no longer copy captions between our app and instagram

Comment: Running into the same issue...hoping it wasn't Instagram's attempt at preventing apps from spamming a ton of hashtags. This feature was really useful to apps for building communities around their photo filters / cameras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best response I've gotten so far:

> Thanks for your report and interest in the Instagram platform. We are aware of this issue and it will be fixed in the next update of the iOS app.

I followed up asking for a timeframe or anymore info on a workaround but have not heard anything.

Comment: Good. That is the best news so far. :) Did you send an email to IG team? They said Google group of IG developer would be shut down and it was a good idea to post my question to here. But no official response here so far.

Comment: Yes - they're shooting for a hotfix before apple takes their holiday at the end of December

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Instagram Version 5.0.1.

It appears that they have removed the caption url parameter from their URL scheme though. So UIDocumentInteractionController can still pass a caption through the annotation property but trying to add one through the URL scheme is no longer supported.